Running Llama2 on 8 GPUs with triton without tensor parallelism
I want to run nvidia's triton server with tensorrt_llm backend serving llama2-7b on 8 GPUs. The guide creates the model with tensor parallelism ( --tp_size 4 ) but I don't want to do that. I just want 1-gpu model to be loaded on each GPU. I have more than enough memory for that (GPU are L40S with 48GB VRAM). When I just set the --world-size 8  I got an assertion fail, that requires the model to use either tensor or pipeline parallelism to use more GPUs.
How I can run triton with same model on each GPU ?
